# How can I make it easier to live-feed my frogs?

Tags: feeding, frogs, amphibians

I used to have [Indonesian Floating Frogs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occidozyga_lima) (they go by many names, but this is what my pet store called them), and while I found them cute and such, I struggled a lot with making sure they stayed fed, as they need to be fed live food (pinhead crickets were recommended to me). It wasn't that I was too scared to touch the crickets, but they were prone to escaping the moment I opened their little plastic box house. The whole thing was quite stressful, as I found it so difficult to make sure my little froggies got fed (and I suspect they died because of underfeeding, which makes me feel -terrible-).

How can I make it easier to feed them if I choose to get more frogs in the future?

Answer (score 13):

We have a White's tree frog and an American toad, and feed live crickets to both.  We've had good success with this box, which is available at pet stores:

[image: Lee's Kricket Keeper]

The box comes with a very nice mechanism for transferring the crickets to your frog cage.  In the picture, you can see the two black tubes sticking out.  The tubes are capped on one end and removable.  Inside the box, the crickets can travel up the tubes and sit inside.  Then when it is time to feed crickets to the frogs, you just pull one of the tubes out and stick your hand over the open end to prevent the crickets from getting out.  Then you can shake the crickets out into the frog cage.  If you want to coat the crickets with vitamins for the frog, you can use the tube as a shaker.

Comment: poor crickets :)

Comment: What size crickets have you used with this? I've read a number of reviews online that says the holes are too big and the crickets crawl out. Since the OP says they're going to be using pinhead crickets, this might be a problem. Have you used it with small crickets or only with big ones?

Comment: @starsplusplus I've used it with all different size crickets, ranging from pinhead to 1 inch (large), and I've never had a problem with crickets escaping through the holes. The holes are on the top and the crickets sit on the bottom, and I've never seen a cricket climb the walls or the outside of the black tubes.

Comment: I wonder why there are so many reviews that say that. What else do you have in the box besides the crickets?

Comment: @starsplusplus The only thing I put in the box besides the crickets is some cricket gel for food/water; no substrate of any kind, and no egg cartons or other material for them to climb.  I put about 2 dozen crickets in the box at a time, and when there aren't any live ones left, I rinse it out with hot water before I put new ones in.  And although the crickets can hop a little, I've never seen one climb the walls or the outside of the tubes to get anywhere near the holes in the top.  I can't explain any reviews that say otherwise.

Comment: That might be it, then.