# How much should I feed Indonesian Floating Frogs?

Tags: feeding, frogs, amphibians

I already asked about [how to make it easier](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-can-i-make-it-easier-to-live-feed-my-frogs) to feed my frogs, but now I wonder how much they should be getting to eat. The pet store just said "until they don't eat the crickets", but I never knew if I should give them time to eat them, or just stop if they aren't eating them right away.

How many crickets should I feed each frog, if I am feeding them crickets (or is there something better I can feed them)? They would be adult frogs, if that helps.

Answer (score 6):

Information specific to Indonesian floating frogs is somewhat thin on the ground. However, a common guideline for fish and other aquatic pets is "as much as they can eat in two minutes".
The number of crickets they can eat will also depend on the size of the crickets.

I'm generally in favour of offering a varied diet. Indonesian floating frogs tend to prefer live food, so diet may depend on what's available in your area. Small insects, worms, and larvae such as glass worms/mosquito larvae, blood worms, black worms, house flies, fruit flies, brine shrimp, daphnia, and crickets all make appropriate foodstuffs.

If your frogs are used to being hand/tweezer fed then you may be able to get them to accept some frozen foods. Glass worms, blood worms, brine shrimp and various others are often available frozen at pet stores.